# getting error while opening Client Dashboard for Dask bag

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

- Getting this ERROR while opening Dask Client Dashboard

```
This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

- Code

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress

client = Client(n_workers = 4, threads_per_worker = 1)
client
```

- Output

```
- Client
  - Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:46851
  - Dashboard: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status
- Cluster
  - Workers: 4
  - Cores: 4
  - Memory: 27.31 GB
```